# Combining multiple views together in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a site set up in ASP.NET MVC3 right now, but the layout of everything is optimized for mobile devices.

I would now like to combine some of the existing views together to take advantage of the additional screen space in a desktop browser or tablet.

I have two views now, one displaying a list of links and a second displaying some content generated by each link; both these views are handled by separate controllers. Here is the list view (simplified). It uses a layout page, so this is what would be displayed when `@RenderBody()` is called in the layout (my second view also works like this, with the same layout file).

```
@model IEnumerable<CommandCenterEntity>
@{
    if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice) {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutMobileContent.cshtml";
    }
    else {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutDesktop.cshtml";
    }
}
<ul data-role="listview" id="commandcenterlist" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" data-theme="b">
    @foreach (var entity in Model)
    {
    <li>
        @Html.CommandCenterLinks(@entity, x => Url.Action("Index", "Worksheet", new { ParentId = @entity.ID_Item }))
    </li>
    }
</ul>
```

The CommandCenterLinks helper just generates an "a" tag containing a different icon depending on some properties of the entity.

I'd like to combine my views in such a way that when I click a link in the list, which would be in a div tag on the left of the screen, the generated content will display in a separate div tag on the right.

I was hoping I could reuse the same actions/controllers used in my mobile layout, so I tried using jQuery to intercept the click event on the list and capture the data returned from the action, and inject it into the div:

```
$(document).on("click", "#commandcenterlist a", function (e) {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();        
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        success: function (data) {
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            $("#desktopContentPane").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

However, the data I get back in the ajax success handler contains the full html page,

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head>...</head>
    <body>...</body>
</html>
```

...when all I want is the content that would have been generated in the layout's `@RenderBody()` call. I tried changing the controller method to have `return PartialView("Index");`, but it gave the same result. Is there a way for me to get back only that portion of the view? Or is there some cleaner, more "MVC" way of going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is really to return your partial view from a separate controller action. So, a few things I would change to make it work:

1. Take the content you want to share (whatever you want to display in the div for desktop) and put it in a partial view.
2. Create a controller action which returns just this partial view (use the [PartialView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470145.aspx) method and pass in your partial view name), and call it from your javascript in the desktop version.
3. In view for the mobile version, you can use the [RenderPartial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial.aspx) method to include the contents from the partial view in your mobile page.

Comment: I still need to do some testing, but this seems to work. Thanks!